# Is it possible to use Bamboo for iOS CI?

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, bamboo

Is it possible to use Bamboo for iOS CI? Since all developers on my company using Bamboo on their projects (Java based), I would like also to use Bamboo as a platform for iOS CI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to do iOS CI on Mac OS.
If that's true then it's possible and I have setup that topology in my company, using a server-agent approach.

Bamboo agent is a Java program which could be run on Mac OS. Let the agent talk to your current Bamboo server and handle all iOS build/test.

Comment: Hi @Liem Pham, just wonder if you use this plugin for the integration : https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.xcode.bamboo-xcode-plugin/server/overview ?

Answer (score 1):

Bamboo does not officially support iOS as a 1st class citizen yet. However, there is [this beta "labs" project](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/xcode-354353193.html?_ga=1.65194667.468504742.1452715047) that looks promising. It seems to suggest that official support is incoming soon. I too would love for Atlassian to include iOS/XCode project support.